# What's the influence of compiling ORACLE packages with DEBUG

Tags: oracle, debugging, plsql

we compile all our Oracle Packages with the DEBUG option enabled. This is the default for our IDE (PLSQLDeveloper). So when we compile a package in the background the following is executed:

```
ALTER PACKAGE emp_mgmt
   COMPILE DEBUG PACKAGE;
```

I wonder if there are any performance consequences for this. The Oracle docs about [ALTER PACKAGE](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_2005.htm) do not mention anything about this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a whole range of [optimizations that the PL/SQL compiler](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm) can do.

[Setting the mode to debug is equivalent to setting the optimizer level to 1](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/alter_function.htm) (disabling most of the optimizations)

So it could have a significant impact on performance.

Comment: +1 for documentation and references. Could you leave an excerpt of the docs? I've read somewhere in SO that the community should stand on his on so leaving the extract here prevents the loss in case the reference disappears.

Comment: great. Thanks for the references.

Comment: Appears both links are now dead.

Answer (score 4):

Oracle provides a Debug API for IDE developers. In the case that a Package is compiled with the `DEBUG` option, it is possible to set breaktpoints with that API. If you compiled all packages with the `DEBUG` option, someone can set a breakpoint via that API to manipulate the system!

So I think it is more an security issue than a preformance problem to compile Packages in debug mode.

**EDIT:**
[`SET_BREAKPOINT` Function](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_debug.htm#i1009232) in the Oracle documentation

Comment: Thanks. I did know the meaning of the DEBUG option, but it's good that you pointed out the security issue for this, although it's not an issue in my environments. I Still wonder if it gives impact to the performance.

Comment: @Robe Eleckers: Can you accept the answer with the grey hook please? But only if it the right one! To the preformance: I think in the past were prefermance issues possible, but not today anymore!

Comment: I will wait for other answers before accepting this, since it does not completely answer my question.

Answer (score 2):

Compiling with the debug option definitely affects performance. A simple test that loops 50,000 times calculating a metaphone for example (lots of string tests, if then else ...)  takes twice the time in debug mode.